# Java console from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, console, user-input, java-6

I am trying to implement the Java 6 console api. If I am trying to run my java class as `Java Application` why is my console null? Or shall I be running my .java from command promt like `c:workspace>java -cp . console`

My console.java class

```
    public class console{
    public static void main(String s[])throws IOException
    {
    Console c=System.console();
    if(c==null)     
    {
     System.err.println("Console object is not available");
    }
    else{
     String name = null;
     name = c.readLine("Enter any String: ");
   ...}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429). Seems like you'd need to use the command line.